# Bootstrap dropdown not closing on click elsewhere or only works once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have seen this question, but nobody seems to be asking the same thing. I have changed the default functionality of bootstrap drop down to remain open when clicked inside. However I have the following code that does seem to do what I need, however it only works once any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
    $('.basket_toggle').on('click', function (event) {
    var that = $(this);
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').mouseleave(function() {
        $(document).bind("click", function () {
            that.parent().toggleClass('open');
            $(document).unbind( "click" );
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).unbind( "click" );
```

This line unbind click event from document and then not bind it again. So it will work only once.

Try add mouseleave event dynamically :

```
$('.basket_toggle').on('click', function (event) {
    var that = $(this);
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').on("mouseleave",function() {
        $(document).bind("click", function () {
            that.parent().toggleClass('open');
            $(document).unbind( "click" );
        });
    });
});
```